# How do I encrypt a password insert it into the db and after the comparison when he will want to connect?

Tags: spring, postgresql, encryption, spring-security, password-encryption

How do I encrypt a password insert it into the db and after the comparison when he will want to connect?

I would use Spring security 3.1.

Link Doc Spring : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/crypto.html Link API SPring security 3.1.4 : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/apidocs/

Comment: Please don't encrypt passwords...

Answer (score 2):

Hash the password and store it in database.. when login hash the password which enters and compare it with the password which is stored in database..

check this link.. may help you...

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-password-hashing-example/